# Export / save data to next available row within column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to save data from a particular cell to another sheet. On said sheet I need it to save to the next available row within a defined column.
I have the script below that will save the data to the next available row, but am unsure of how to define the column.
In the example below, I'd need it to be saved into the 'A' column.

```
function transferList() {

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D5").getValues();
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet12");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow();
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);

}
```

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer, I hope this is useful to you. I'm not completely sure whether that's what you wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you want to write this to the first empty cell of a specific column (which may not correspond to the first empty row in the sheet).

#### Solution:

I'd suggest using [Range.getNextDataCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection) to find the last cell before the first empty one, and [Range.offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to get that empty one.

#### Code sample:

```
function transferList() {
  var columnIndex = 1; // Column A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet12");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(1,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(2,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);
}
```

#### Note:

Since you are getting a value from a single cell, there's no need to use `getValues` and `setValues`; you can use [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I've tried altering my code to replicate what you've detailed, but keep getting 'Range not found'. - I've tried this on a fresh sheet too & get the same.

Comment: @comiconor There was a typo in the code I provided which I already fixed. It should be working now, I just tested it.

Comment: @comiconor You're welcome, glad to know your issue was solved!

Comment: out of curiosity, how would I change the code so instead of going into the 'A' column, it when into say the 'D' column? (Sorry if it's really simple, just trying to learn this).

Comment: @comiconor Just change `columnIndex` from `1` to `4`.

Comment: I have done. It works for the first entry, but then doesn't input onto the next row as it does within the 'A' column. - Very confused.

Comment: @comiconor Cannot reproduce this, it's working for me. Maybe there are some cells which you think are empty but are not. Consider providing a copy of your spreadsheet to test this (free of sensitive information).

Comment: I think I've figured it out now (my fault) targetSS.getRange(1,columnIndex) needed to be changed to targetSS.getRange(2,columnIndex) as there was no entry in the first row within the column. - - Thank you again for the help & support!